# Actual Sales VS Target report / dashboard

Tags: administration, dashboard, joined-reports, forecast, reports-api

I have task where I need to create Actual sales vs Quota/target report & dashboard. I have searched internet but couldn't able to find solution. And forms stated that it's not possible to generate such reports. Please let know me the best case or solutions where I could generate such report.

FYI - Quota / targets are in Opportunities report and Actual sales [Forecasted & closed] are in Forecasting report.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this tip on Creating Sales vs. Goal Reports and Dashboards in the Salesforce success community? It has worked out really well for my company, and has made my life in creating reports so much easier! https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hs6gAAA

Comment: Yes I saw that post... but I need by weekly basis on x-axis